# Using a Select in a like clause for another Select

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in my sql server 2012. First table is tblInvoiceChange_Log which has data like this,

```
log_id       log_date                description
------------------------------------------------
 123     2014-05-16 05:20:39.393     BL1202 locked
 124     2014-08-21 03:12:05.143     BL0293 unlocked
  -              -                           -
  -              -                           -
```

There is another table tblInvoice which has data like this,

```
Bill_Number    created_by_id     created_by_name
-------------------------------------------------
BL1202           3081               ABC
BL0293           5236               XYZ
  -               -                  -
  -               -                  -
```

I want to get all the log information where the substring of "description" column matches the "Bill_Number" column of another table.

I tried the following query but it gives me an error saying "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

```
select * from tblInvoiceChange_Log (nolock)
where description like '%' + (select distinct Bill_Number
from tblInvoice (nolock)) + '%'
```

How can I achieve this? Any ideas will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `like` in a join:

```
select * 
from tblInvoiceChange_Log (nolock) a
join (select distinct Bill_Number from tblInvoice (nolock)) b 
    on a.description like '%' + b.Bill_Number  + '%'
```